# Run Cron Job Every 15 Minutes in specific time and every day

Tags: php, cron

I'am trying using cron job and want to run every day and every minutes from 07.00 AM until 07.00 PM
i try this :

```
*/15 7-19 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/path/file.php
```

i got error like this :

```
"-":3: bad command
errors in crontab file, can't install.
```

just fetting error, please help me.

Comment: Please post your error and system information: `uname -sr`

Comment: i have been edit the post question, please see

Comment: Replace `*/15` with `15` and see if it helps.

Comment: getting error again /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: 15: command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never posted your system details: `uname -sr`

Cron on some systems does not allow `/` and `-` construct. Remove existing and create below entry:-

```
15 7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/path/file.php
```